# Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:

Tags: web3js, blockchain, erc-20, etherscan, infura

I have tried all sorts of ways but it's not working for me when i change my value to 0 it works fine the transaction gets submitted.

But if i change it to any other number lets say 1, 10, 20 I get this error.

I have created my owntoken

[image]

MyAbi File

```
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "previousOwner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "newOwner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "OwnershipTransferred",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "owner",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "renounceOwnership",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "newOwner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transferOwnership",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_owner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "balanceOf",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "balance",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "_value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transfer",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "success",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "_from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "_to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "_value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Transfer",
        "type": "event"
    }
]
```

MyJavascriptCode

````
    var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;
    var Web3 = require('web3');
    var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/$[project_key]'));

    var amount = web3.utils.toHex(1);
    var privateKey = Buffer.from('myprivatekey', 'hex');
    var abiArray = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('MyAbi.json'));
    var contractAddress = '0x37FC4b48CE93'; // ONLYONE address
    const amountToSend = 10
    console.log("23")
    
    var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddress, {from: fromAddress});
    console.log("24")
 

    var count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress);
    // count = '0x' + count.toString(16)

    var rawTransaction = {
        "gasPrice":web3.utils.toHex(10000000000),
        "gasLimit":web3.utils.toHex(8000000),
        "to":contractAddress,
        "value": 1,
        "data":contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, amount).encodeABI(),
        "nonce":web3.utils.toHex(count)
    };

    var transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction, {chain:'ropsten'});
    transaction.sign(privateKey)

    var result = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'), function(err, res){
        if(err){
            console.log("err-->", err)
        }else{
            console.log("response--->", res)
        }
    });
    return result;
}

sendOnlyone(fromAdd, '0x11cE'); //fromaddress , toaddress```
````

Comment: How did you solved it?

Answer (score 2):

According to your abi, you transfer method is not payable, but you set the value of you transaction payload to one wei { … value: 1, (…) }

To use your transfer method (and, therefore, transfer your token), set the *value of your transaction* to 0 and the *parameter of your transfer function* to the desired amount.